# javah is not a recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, android, sdk

I tried to fix this by executing in my cmd: "path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin"

I'm working on windows. 
Is this wrong? I've been stuck for awhile so any help would much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javah is under `<JAVA_HOME>/bin` folder, you have to ensure that you have that folder on your path

you can do something like (on unix system)

```
export PATH=<JAVA_HOME>/bin:$PATH
```

or follow this for windows

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I tried it and when I type "Path" it points to PATH=$Path:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin. However, I'm still getting the error. Any reason you could think of ?

Comment: Could you please tell how you fixed it?

Answer (score 5):

javah is removed in the latest JDK.

Before JDK 8, you need to compile the Java program using javac and generate C/C++ header using a dedicated javah utility. The javah utility is no longer available in JDK 10.

For those who are using the latest JDK, 
 the javac -h command will compile and create a header file.